SQL shows me the same data 4 times - although I have only one - why?
I am new to SQL and right now I learn joins. The problem is in my table cars_equipment, it shows my one row 4 times. Why?
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.model,
    c.description,
    c.environment,
    c.equipment,
    c.ps,
    c.tuv,
    c.cover,
    c.brand,
    c.price,
    c.engine,
    c.fuel,
    c.firstregistration,
    c.km,
    c.color,
    c.video,
    c.type,
    c.show,
    c.sit_place,
    array_agg(ci.image) as images,
    array_agg(ce.name) as equipments
FROM 
    cars c
LEFT JOIN 
    cars_images ci ON ci.car_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN 
    cars_equipment ce ON ce.car_id = c.id
WHERE 
    c.show IS TRUE AND c.id = $1 
GROUP BY 
    c.id, ce.id
LIMIT 1;

What am I doing wrong?
If I remove the group by ce.id, then the query returns 20x null values and 4x times the same value

Because there are 4 entries in cars_equipment ce where  ce.car_id = c.id

And because you have include ce.id in your GROUP BY

Sample data and expected results for all relevant tables are essential to understand what's going on. Almost certainly the issue is multiple many-to-one joins, which means you get a cartesian product between all the child tables. You need to pre-aggregate on car_id before joining.
